# How to configure / describe deployment of a web app in Git in combination with Ansible

Tags: git, docker, ansible

I want to deploy several web apps directly from their Git repository

A single web app consists of two docker containers, one for a Apache Tomcat (as middleware and for serving static files, e.g. the Vue.js frontend) and a Mysql database container.

The Ubuntu server itself will be initialized from scratch with an Ansible playbook providing e.g. docker/docker-compose and a preconfigured Apache Webserver, which will be used as a reverse proxy for all web apps (which are virtual hosts for the Apache Webserver).

A second Ansible playbook install a web app by creating a new user on the Ubuntu server, cloning the repository of the web app from a Git server and configuring the reverse proxy on the Apache Webserver.

Is there a good way to configure / describe the deployment of the web app in its Git repository? This description should take e.g. the name of the docker-compose file, how to build the war file of the middleware software, where to deploy the war file relative to the home directory of the web apps user in the Ubuntu server and so on. Does anyone know by chance if there is a standardized approach to reach my goal?

Comment: The web app is not also run from a Docker container?

Comment: The web app itself will run in two docker containers, one for Apache Tomcat and one for the Mysql database.

Comment: I mean the "second Ansible playbook" part. Can the new user, the app's source code from Git, and whatever web server is running the app all be put into a `Dockerfile`?

Comment: The second Ansible playbook is used every time, when the a new web app will be deployed. The web apps itself is separated in two (or sometimes more) `Dockerfile`s depending on the web apps needs. Bringing it all to one `Dockerfile` will not be possible. But at the moment I use `docker-compose.yml` for orchestating the containers.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the normal approach would be to use a CI/CD environment.

The Git is storing the source code of your project. Every commit (or on any event you want), a Continous integration process starts and compiles the source as needed. In case of a specific branch (master/production) the CI/CD process creates an artefact that is packed into a Docker image and pushed to a registry. All of this isn't done on the server - but on another machine - don't use your Ubuntu production machine to compile the webapp...

Then the CI/CD process can start the publish process either by doing it directly on the remote machine or by calling an ansible playbook (for example to generate the ReverseProxy settings too). So you have completly detached the compile process from the configuration. The playbook could be part of the project.

There are several example for Gitlab and Jenkins available - have a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html for example.

Every project has its own Dockerfile describing the service itself. And there is a overall project with the Docker-Compose file and maybe Ansible Scripts to generate the production environment (generally). The per service configuration is done with playbooks per SCM project.

Changing a file in one project will recreate the Docker image. You only need to call a docker-compose pull & up -d (maybe you don't need to rerun the complete docker-compose-Create process). The other task could be run automatically or on any changes too. I think, the trick is to use a Docker container instead of an Ansible script here, because you already use a docker-compose environment - use it completely.

So - you have (for example)

- a host for development

  - a Gitlab container together with a Gitlab-Runner container

    - per project there is a CI configuration to descibe the tasks from source to artefact (see .gitlab-ci.yml)
    - a Dockerfile to describe the image and its configuration/startup/healthcheck
    - and maybe a playbook that is run by .gitlab-ci.yml to configure the ReverseProxy etc.
    - one different project with the inventory and generic playbooks to create the default setup for your environment (in my case a push to that project calls a AWX REST API to reread the SCM and start a playbook site.yml).
  - maybe a Docker Registry
  - maybe in front of that a ReverseProxy.
- and you production machine

  - a ReverseProxy
  - several Docker-compose environments with docker-images from your registry

The nice thing is - together with AWX and some other hosts you could create staging area for different branches and new projects and use time based deployment too.

Of course - replace Gitlab with whatever you want.